# cordova-support-google-services is no longer needed for cordova apps?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, cordova, google-play-services

When I try to update cordova-support-google-services I get this warning:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-support-google-services --save
Installing "cordova-support-google-services" for android
Plugin doesn't support this project's cordova-android version. cordova-android: 10.1.2, failed version requirement: <9.0.0
Skipping 'cordova-support-google-services' for android
Installing "cordova-support-google-services" for browser
Installing "cordova-support-google-services" for ios
Adding cordova-support-google-services to package.json
```

It only refers to Android. In my app I have Android and iOS platforms.

I'm guessing support was added by cordova and the plugin is no longer needed. If so, what's the new way to add google-services.json (and GoogleService-Info.plist) to the project?

I'm using the latest versions as of June 2022:

- Cordova 11.0.0
- Android 10.1.2
- ios 6.2.0

Comment: "DEPRECATION NOTICE: no longer needed. Use preference GradlePluginGoogleServicesEnabled for cordova-android version 9 or higher." https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-support-google-services

Comment: Sounds like an answer @SergioRinaudo! 

Comment: Thank you @SergioRinaudo, the Android part is solved. But for iOS I can't find a similar solution.

Comment: Sorry, I've never had a chance to compile cordova for Apple devices :/